# Unable to read and send the output of the count of table through email

Tags: shell-script, shell

Tried to figure out but could not find much help. I want to capture the count of the table and send an email if the count is more than 0.
The output in the email should be as shown below only if it crosses the count more than 0. Please help, thanks in advance for helping me out.

```
spool log;

SELECT count(*)
FROM users
;

spool off

EOF


count=`grep -rn  log | wc -l`
if [ $count != "1" ]
then
cat log | mailx -r example@gmail.com " ${MAILTO} > /dev/null 2>&1
else
echo "No Sessions found"
fi
```

Output:

```
Count(*)
--------
      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify the work you can replace:

```
count=`grep -rn  log | wc -l`
if [ $count != "1" ]
```

with

```
count=`tail -1  log`
if ["$count" -gt 0 ]
```

the `sql` will return only one value (this is the idea of `count(*)` command) so do not need of `wc -l`, just grab the last line. And use `-eq` when compare numbers in `bash`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Romeo but it is not comparing and says no sessions found. Below is the output. 
`++ tail -2 log
+ count='      14'
+ '[' 14 -eq 1 ']'
+ echo 'No Sessions found'
No Sessions found`

Comment: @James, my mistake, I edit the answer, should be `-ne`, not `-eq`. ANd use `-1` in `tail`, `-2` will get two lines. If you have the number one line before the last use `tail -2 log|head -1`

Comment: @Roman It worked but not as expected. It should send an alert when the count is greater than 0 and the alert should not be triggered when the count is 0. Please help me in this.

Comment: @James, check my edited answer

Comment: @Roman Thank you so much, please tell me what does that -ne and -gt does. If possible can you share the links through which I can refer to learn more about how to apply this function.

Comment: @James, for the record my name is Romeo. `-ne` mean not equivalent for numbers, `-gt` great than (again for numbers). You can check manuals for `bash` about the things :)

Comment: Apologize for addressing you incorrectly. Thank you so much for your help.